# How to implement drag drop and swap using Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have multiple divs, I need to implement drag, drop and swap functionality, means If I have two divs div1 and div2. So When User drags div1 and drops div1 on div2, it should swap the position of both divs.

```
<div class="flex-container" *ngFor="let rowdata of rowno;let i = index" >
<div *ngFor="let columndata of colno;let j = index">
    <div id={{loadData(this.finalsequence)}} draggable="true" (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" (dragstart)="drag($event)">
        <div style="position: relative;" attr.>test</div>
        <div>{{(i* colno.length) + (j + 1)}}</div>
        <div>{{this.dict.get((i* colno.length) + (j + 1))}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```